# VBA - Safely store variable reference

Tags: vba, ms-access, reference

I'm familiar with passing an argument to a procedure by reference. Alternately, `ParamArray` allows me the flexibility of passing 0 or more arguments to a procedure by reference as well.  However, that approach made me wonder if there was a way to preserve a reference to one or more variables beyond the scope of a procedure.  My first glimmer of hope was the VBA `Array` function when I saw it was declared like this:

`Array(ParamArray ArgList() As Variant)`

So, I put together the following test code:

```
Private Sub Test()

    Dim a   As Object
    Dim b() As Variant

    ParamArrayTest a
    Debug.Print TypeName(a) ' Output is 'Dictionary'
    b = Array(a)            ' b should be like ParamArray ArgList()
    Set b(0) = Nothing      ' This should clear a
    Debug.Print TypeName(a) ' Output is still 'Dictionary'

End Sub

Private Sub ParamArrayTest(ParamArray ArgList() As Variant)

    Set ArgList(0) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

End Sub
```

Unfortunately, this did not work as I expected.  Despite the argument being passed into the `Array` function via `ParamArray`, it would appear that the returned array was by value and not by reference.

Further research led me to the undocumented VBA `VarPtr` / `StrPtr` / `ObjPtr` functions.  I found numerous examples of using them in conjunction with the API `RtlMoveMemory` function.  However, all of the articles I read strongly urged against using that approach since it could very easily crash the application.  Some of my testing did indeed crash Access.

Another idea I had was to see if I could directly assign a reference of one variable to another:

```
Private Sub Test()

    Dim a As Object
    Dim b As Variant

    b = ByRef a ' Throws a compiler error

End Sub
```

Suffice it to say, the compiler simply would not allow that.  My question then is, can a variable reference be safely stored / preserved beyond the scope of a procedure (preferably in another variable)?

## EDIT

I decided it would be more helpful if I shed some light on what I'm trying to build.

I'm currently in the process of creating a wrapper class which will pass all form / control events to a procedure in one of my modules.  It will be used with 2 forms which have the same control structure but connect to different source tables.  Bear in mind that the code is incomplete but should be sufficient to illustrate the problem I'm trying to overcome.  Also, `Database` is my VBA project name.

There are four portions to the code:

1. `Form_TEST_FORM` - Form Module

   ```
   Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

       FormHub.InitForm Me, Cancel

   End Sub
   ```
2. `FormHub` - Module

   ```
   Public Sub InitForm( _
       ByRef Form As Access.Form, _
       ByRef Cancel As Integer _
   )

       Dim Evt As Database.EventHandler

       Set Evt = New Database.EventHandler
       Evt.InitFormObject Form, Cancel
       FormList.Add Evt, Form.Name

   End Sub

   Private Function FormList() As VBA.Collection

       Static Init As Boolean
       Static Coll As VBA.Collection

       If Not Init Then

           Set Coll = New VBA.Collection
           Init = True

       End If

       Set FormList = Coll

   End Function
   ```
3. `FormControl` - Class Module

   ```
   Public Ptr      As Variant ' Pointer to form control variable
   Public acType   As Access.AcControlType
   ```
4. `EventHandler` - Class Module

   ```
   Private WithEvents Form     As Access.Form
   Private WithEvents SForm    As Access.SubForm
   Private CtrlList            As VBA.Collection

   Private Sub Class_Initialize()

       InitCtrlList

   End Sub

   Public Sub InitFormObject(FormObj As Access.Form, ByRef Cancel As Integer)

       Dim ErrFlag As Boolean
       Dim Ctrl    As Access.Control
       Dim FCtrl   As Database.FormControl

       On Error GoTo Proc_Err

       Set Form = FormObj

       If Form.Controls.Count <> CtrlList.Count Then

           Err.Raise 1, , _
           "Form has incorrect number of controls"

       End If

       ' This is where I want to validate the form controls
       ' and also initialize my event variables.
       For Each Ctrl In Form.Controls

           If Not CtrlExists(FCtrl, Ctrl.Name) Then

               Err.Raise 2, , _
               "Invalid control name"

           ElseIf FCtrl.acType <> Ctrl.ControlType Then

               Err.Raise 3, , _
               "Invalid control type"

           Else

               ' Initialize the correct variable with it's
               ' pointer.  This is the part I haven't been
               ' able to figure out yet.
               Set FCtrl.Ptr = Ctrl

           End If

       Next

   Proc_End:

       On Error Resume Next

       If ErrFlag Then

           ClearEventVariables

       End If

       Set Ctrl = Nothing
       Set FCtrl = Nothing

       Exit Sub

   Proc_Err:

       ErrFlag = True
       Debug.Print "InitFormObject " & _
       "Error " & Err & ": " & Err.Description
       Resume Proc_End

   End Sub

   Private Function CtrlExists( _
       ByRef FCtrl As Database.FormControl, _
       ByRef CtrlName As String _
   ) As Boolean

       On Error Resume Next

       Set FCtrl = CtrlList(CtrlName)
       CtrlExists = Err = 0

   End Function

   Private Sub InitCtrlList()

       Set CtrlList = New VBA.Collection
       CtrlList.Add SetCtrlData(SForm, acSubform), "SForm"

   End Sub

   Private Function SetCtrlData( _
       ByRef Ctrl As Access.Control, _
       ByRef acType As Access.AcControlType _
   ) As Database.FormControl

       Set SetCtrlData = New Database.FormControl

       With SetCtrlData

           ' This assignment is where I need to keep a reference
           ' to the variable in the class.  However, it doesn't
           ' work.
           Set .Ptr = Ctrl
           .acType = acType

       End With

   End Function

   Private Sub ClearEventVariables()

       Dim FormCtrl As Database.FormControl

       Set Form = Nothing

       For Each FormCtrl In CtrlList

           ' Assuming I was able to retain a reference to the
           ' class variable, this would clear it.
           Set FormCtrl.Ptr = Nothing

       Next

   End Sub

   Private Sub Class_Terminate()

       ClearEventVariables
       Set CtrlList = Nothing

   End Sub
   ```

I only used 1 control in the code example for simplicity sake.  But, the idea is to simplify how much code I would need to modify in order to add / remove controls should the form design change.  Or, in the event I have to add more forms to the project.

Comment: Exactly what do you mean with "*preserve a reference to one or more variables beyond the scope of a procedure*"? Your question is rather unclear.

Comment: @Mat'sMug For instance, if I pass a variable into a procedure `ByRef` I'm able to modify the source variable's value by modifying the procedure argument.  But, as soon as the procedure exits, I lose the pointer to the source variable.  I want to safely store the pointer to the source variable so I can update it's value outside the scope of a single procedure.  Please let me know if this explanation makes more sense.

Comment: It's the "I lose the pointer to the source variable" part that doesn't make any sense to me. When the procedure exits, you're back at the caller, where *you already have* the variable you were passing `ByRef`. I just don't see what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I see what you mean.  I'll try to come up with some better code examples and update my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to reference only within a single module, declare as Public in module header. If you want to reference in any module, declare as Global in a general module header. Even array and recordset and connection objects can be declared this way. Be aware these variables will lose their values if code breaks in runtime.

Or look into TempVar object variables. They don't lose values if code breaks. But can only store number or text values, not objects.